# 'Gdiplus::Graphics' : no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: constructor, gdi+

```
Not sure what I am doing wrong.. I have a very muddy idea of how Constructors should be formatted or structured, so any insights would help!
```

```
    Renderer.h
```

```
#pragma once

#include <afxwin.h>
#include <winapifamily.h>
#include <wtypes.h>

#include <gdiplus.h>

class Renderer
{
public:
Renderer();
~Renderer();


void Clear(Gdiplus::Color clearColor);

virtual void Free() = 0;
virtual void LoadFace(int index, char* path) = 0;
void InitFromHDC(HDC dc);
void Shutdown();

// Drawing surface
Gdiplus::Graphics _graphics;
```

protected:

private:

```
bool _gdiplusActive;
```

};

Renderer.cpp

Renderer::Renderer()
: _gdiplusActive(false)
{   // <-error here
}

Renderer::~Renderer() {}

...

I tried many variation of adding variables... but honestly, the error may be obvious who understands what a default constructor is. I dunno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A default constructor is a construtor that takes no parameters.

You can't create a Gdiplus::Graphics out of thin air, you need to give it something to draw on: a bitmap, a window or a device context.

Here is the list of constructors available:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-graphics(constgraphics_)